# how to compile vtk-master with qt5 and visual sudio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, qt5, vtk, qvtkwidget

When I compile the vtk-master with vs 2015(update 1) and QT5, I see an error as:
Error   C2039   'Frame': is not a member of 'QGL Widget'    GUI Support Qt Open GL  C:\VTK\SOURCE\source\GUISupport\QtOpenGL\QVTKWidget2.cxx    488

How can I fix this error?

Comment: This class was removed from VTK master here : 

https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/6506

Update your repository using `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have any circular dependencies like follows,

```
A.h depends on B.h and B.h depends on A.h
```

This problem can be easily solved by using `typedef`

Comment: i installed QT5.14.1 (VS 2015 ) with QT offline installer before compiling , but that error occurred.
i used vtk-master, VS2015(update 1) , cmake 3.16.4 and  QT5.14.1 VS 2015 .
qt options:
VTK_BUILD_QT_DESIGNER_PLUGIN : checked
VTK_GROUP_ENABLE_Qt= yes
VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQt= want
VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtOpenGL=want
VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtSQL = want
VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_RenderingQt = want
VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_ViewsQt= want

  Error C2039 ‘Frame’: is not a member of ‘QGLWidget’ GUISupportQtOpen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling VTK with the same configuration as your Qt installation (e.g., VS2015 and Release). I have a tutorial on YouTube using VS2017 that you can check out:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkjbuaHoEQvhhWNE3PHdVFAhqviZsjMFO